# Multihomed VM workgroup attached to domain clients, resolution issues

Tags: domain, virtual-machines, workgroup, multi-homed

hopefully someone here can help me out with this nightmare:

I have a corporate network with ADDS, let's make believe this is a 192.168.10.x network.

I have a server that runs 3 VMs (one APP server, one SQL server and one web server) that are not connected to the corporate domain, but all the clients for these services are on the network domain.  Each VM has 3 NICs (one required admin network between the VMs 192.168.100.x, one network to manage an ISILON storage solution 192.168.101.x, and the network that connects to the corporate domain 192.168.10.x).

I currently have no issues getting to these machines using their 10.x IP addresses.  I can also get to them "sometimes" using their hostname.  The issue is that the hostname I use will round-robin between the 3 different IP addresses assigned to each VM (100.x, 101.x and 10.x).  I've gone in to the IPV4 settings for each NIC on the 100 networks and turned off the DNS option and the NetBios over TCPIP, but this problem still persists.

My question is:  Is there a way to ensure that everytime a hostname like 'vmserver1' is used, it is correctly resolved to 192.168.10.x instead of 100.x or 101.x?  As you can guess, if it resolves to 100.x or 101.x, I get no reply on the corporate domain.

My thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

DNS registration with multiple NIC:

> To disable DNS dynamic update for all names on the computer, clear the
>   Register this connection's addresses in DNS and the Use this
>   connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration check boxes on the DNS tab
>   for all connections in Network Connections.

From: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305553#6

For multiple IP per NIC :

Please use the command; netsh int ipv4 add address "Local Area Network" skipassource=true

> After you install this hotfix, you can assign IP addresses that will
>   not be registered for outgoing traffic on the DNS servers by using a
>   new flag of the netsh command. This new flag is the skipassource flag.
>
> Note You can create IP version 4 (IPv4) addresses and IP version 6
>   (IPv6) addresses by using the netsh command together with the new
>   skipassource flag.
>
> For example, the following command creates an IPv4 address that is not
>   registered for outgoing traffic on the DNS servers:
>
> Netsh int ipv4 add address  
>   skipassource=true

Please check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2386184 & https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2554859

If both method fail please do static A entry in your DNS.

Comment: I mentioned above that I had already done the "Clear the register this connection's address in DNS", and the multiple IP per NIC doesn't apply to my situation.  I'm guessing the problem here is that my machines aren't on the domain, and it's the domain's DNS server that's causing the resolution issues.  Since I don't have admin rights to the domain, I'll have to go a step higher I guess.  Thanks anyways for the effort!